# Finding the number in a list where an element is found for each element in prolog.

Tags: prolog

Ι have attempted to implement a simple program to find the index for every time an element is traversed.

```
indexOf(Found,[Found| T],0).
indexOf(Found,[H| T],Index):- indexOf( Found,T, Newindex),Index is NewIndex+1.
```

I attempted this, but it didn't work; basically I tried recursion here, with incrementation.

If someone could give me insight that would be very appreciated.

Comment: You mistyped `Index` as `Newindex`. Any good Prolog compiler would have warned you about that.

Comment: @larsmans: I think your suggestion should read `NewIndex as Newindex`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it works better (or at all) on long lists, if you write it as

```
index_of(X,L,N) :-
  index_of(X,Xs,0,N) .

index_of( X , [X|_] , N , N ) .
index_of( X , [_|L] , T , N ) :-
  T1 is T+1 ,
  index_of(X,L,T1,N) .
```